# how to attach files that exceed character count limit for thread insertion inline?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have output from a diagnostic I ran on my Mac.  I want to insert the output of the diagnostic into a thread I have, but got the message that it exceeds the character limit.  I then put the file into .pdf and .heic but don't see how to attach a 60 page .pdf or large file .heic.  Is it possible to attach 60 page .pdf or comparable .heic or .txt to a thread?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

You can always upload long log outputs etc to pastebin (or similar sites) and link them. Just make sure they don't contain any sensitive information.

OTOH, long logs hardly ever get read afterwards and are difficult to interpret anyway, so it may not actually help to add them. Usually just adding the relevant parts directly to the question is the better approach.

Comment: ok.  tks.  just making sure there wasn't a way to just use the site here.  As far as the log, id edit it, but I dont know what's relevant and what's not.  Seems lie there is a bunch of nothing going on taking up time, causing the long delay in making the files accessible on the external drive - what im trying to figure out.

Comment: Definitely. Before you post more than 10 lines of text here, think to yourself, why would someone spend the time to review closely dozens and dozens of lines of text to help a poster if they don’t know how to filter and condense what they’re asking. There are good cases for larger chunks, but the system is there to encourage well researched and well scoped problems.

Comment: yep.  get it.  I posted it in the other thread.  I think there is a LOT of repetitive something going on in the file reading.  But, im guessing for someone who knows what to look for, and if were me, id use text search to cut through the excess.  I did not want to delete anything that may give a hint as to whats going on....

Comment: My first response was exactly what my fellow moderators wrote (but less tactful): no one is going to read a 60 page pdf. But you make the point well, Stumped – the idea isn't that someone *should* read a 60 page pdf, but in the hands of someone who knows what they're doing, a quick search might find the relevant information within that PDF, but the whole point of such expertise is that the asker can't summarize the file to the relevant bits precisely because they can't identify them. Well put!